# JAVA - Extract multiple parts from String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a dynamic String (from a SQL query) which looks like this

`String x="abc_123_456_defgh_ijkl_mnop_qr"`

First I separated them with substring(x,y) into different variables but now I figured out that the length of each part could vary. 
Which means I need to separate the strings by character.

Goal is:

```
String x1=abc
String x2=123
String x3=456
String x4=defgh
...
```

I couldn't get regex to work...maybe because I'm quite new to JAVA :( 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use String's split method, and pass "_" as separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split method

```
    String x="abc_123_456_defgh_ijkl_mnop_qr";
    String parts[]=x.split("_");
    String x1=parts[0];
    String x2=parts[1];
            ...
```

You can check more info at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Answer (score 0):

consider to split to underScore:

```
 final String x = "abc_123_456_defgh_ijkl_mnop_qr";
        final String[] xw = x.split("_");
        for (final String s : xw) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you all, it worked fine with Lokesh Agrawal's answer `String parts[]=x.split("_");
    String x1=parts[0];
    String x2=parts[1];`

Answer (score 0):

If you have more delimiters

```
public class StringSplit {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String str = "S t, a, c.k";
   String delimiters = "\\s+|,\\s*|\\.\\s*";

   // analyzing the string 
   String[] values = str.split(delimiters);



   for(String value : values) {
   System.out.print(value);
   } 
   }
}
```